# How to count same group value in each date

Tags: mysql

I have this:

table_user

```
id | name
1 john
2 smith
3 dalton
```

table_order

```
id | dates | user_id
x 2017-01-01 1
x 2017-01-01 1
x 2017-01-01 2
x 2017-01-02 1
x 2017-01-02 3
x 2017-01-02 3
```

I want this result using pure MySQL:

```
dates | john | smith | dalton
2017-01-01 | 2 | 1 | 0
2017-01-02 | 1 | 0 | 2
```

What I can do is only this:

`select a.dates, b.name, count(*) as counts from table_orders a left join table_user b on a.user_id=b.id group by a.dates, b.name`

Result:

```
dates | name | counts
2017-01-01 john 2
2017-01-01 smith 1
2017-01-02 john 1
2017-01-02 dalton 2
```

Then I process using PHP.

So, how to do this using pure MySQL?

Comment: you should use Pivot
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Comment: dont close this yet. ill try looking pivot table now

Comment: ill try to edit my question since pivot table cant work dinamycally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with dynamic sql query.

**Query**

```
set @query = null;
select
  group_concat(distinct
    concat(
      'coalesce(sum(case when `name` = ''',
      `name`, ''' then 1 end), 0) as `', `name` , '`'
    )
  ) into @query
from `your_table_name`;

set @query = concat('select `dates`, ', @query, ' from `your_table_name` 
              group by `dates`
');

prepare stmt from @query;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

### **[`Find a demo here`](http://rextester.com/RAFH22555)**

Comment: wtf. awesome bro. thanks

Comment: @plonknimbuzz : Please mark it as answer if it solved your problem

Comment: ofc i will. i just busy to explore your code XD .sry